# print out skewed text in x86, but can't see why the 'monitored command dumped core' timeout occurs

Tags: string, assembly, x86-64, nested-loops

I am trying to write skewed Text on Terminal via assembly to get my skills going.
Example [] = spaces :

```
H

[]E

[][]L

[][][] L

[][][][] O
```

But I seem to run into a timeout, because I am trying to move a character between registers / get the character via memory address - like getting a char at an index. But it won't really work. I tried working with allocating a byte to increment in the .bss section before, but that lead to a different error which I couldn't work around (relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_8 against `.bss')

Maybe there is a better approach to handle this, and if you could help me get on the right path I would be so so happy. To get more context, here is the 'problematic' snippet of my latest code.

```
    inc rcx ; increase pointer of rcx
space_loop:
    push rdi ;save destination register 
    cmp byte [rcx], 0 ;end of string found
    je eos ; jump to exit subroutine 
    
    mov rax, 4; SYS Write
    mov rbx, 0 ; STDOUT
    cmp rsp,[rbp] ; compare spaceIndex to String Index
    je print_char 
    mov rdi, space ;print space 
    mov rdx,1 ; length = 1
    syscall

    inc byte [rsp] ; increase spaceIndex
    jnz space_loop
    
print_char:
  ;print out char 
  mov rax, 4
  mov rbx, 0
  mov rcx,[rcx] ; <- this line breaks it dont know how to access index here
  mov rdx, 1
  syscall

  call new_Line ; make line break 
  
  inc rcx ; increase rcx counter 
  inc byte [rbp] ; increase index counter
  mov byte [rsp], 0 ;reset space counter
  jmp space_loop; next Line
```

Comment: If you load `rcx` with the char the original value is lost. In any case, the write syscall expects a pointer. As for the relocation error, that happens if you try to use a 8 bit value as an address.

Comment: You have plenty of registers, there's no need to keep your indices on the stack, and the mixed indexing from rbp and rsp makes everything very confusing.  I would also suggest making a [mcve].  With an isolated snippet of the code, it's impossible to tell whether the code makes sense in context.